# Как из глобальной области переменных дать значению в собственную функцию?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Когда дело доходит до функции game(), оно выдаёт ошибку, как мне сосчитать значение переменной choice, понимаю что это разные области, локальные и глобальные, но пока не очень понимаю как они работают.

```
from random import randint
from time import sleep


def intro():
    print('Приветствую в игре "Угадай число')
    sleep(1)
    print('Я загадаю случайное число в определенном диапазоне, ты должен его угадать за определенное количество попыток.')
    sleep(3)

def parameters(rand_begin_number,rand_end_number,Take):  # настройки
    print('1. Изменить диапазон цифр [от] [до]')
    print('2. Изменить количество попыток.')
    parameters_choice = input()
    parameters_choice = int(parameters_choice)

    if parameters_choice == 1:
        print('Введите желаемый диапазон:')
        rand_begin_number = int(input())
        rand_end_number = int(input())
        print('Диапазон установлен: [',rand_begin_number,']', '[',rand_end_number, ']')
    return rand_begin_number,rand_end_number

    if parameters_choice == 2:
        print('Установите количество попыток:')
        Take = int(input())
    return Take


def hello():
    print('Представься, как тебя зовут ?')
    name = input()
    print('Начнём игру,',name,'.')
    return name

def game():
    while choice == 1: 
        primary_rand_begin_number = 1 
        primary_rand_end_number = 20
        primary_Take = 5
        real_number = randint(primary_rand_begin_number,primary_rand_end_number)
        take = primary_Take
    else:
        alt_rand_begin_number = rand_begin_number 
        alt_rand_end_number = rand_end_number
        alt_Take = Take
        real_number = randint(alt_rand_begin_number,alt_rand_end_number)
        take = alt_Take
        fake_take = 1
        print('Введи число:')
        print('ЧИСЛО', real_number)

    for fake_take in range(take):
        user_number = input()
        user_number = int(user_number)
        take -=1
        if user_number != real_number:
            print('Попробуй ещё.')
            print('У тебя осталось', take, 'попыток.')

        if user_number == real_number:
            print('Ты угадал загаданное число [',real_number,'] за', fake_take + 1, 'попыток')
            break

    if user_number != real_number:
        print('Попытки исчерпаны\n')
        print('Загаданное число было:', real_number,'\n')


def startGame():
    print('Начать игру --- нажмите Enter')
    input()

def menu():
    print('1. Начать игру.')
    print('2. Начать заного.(без интро)')
    print('3. Изменить настройки игры.')
    print('4. Выйти из игры.')
    choice = int(input())
    return choice

def quit():
    print('Пока !')
    sleep(1)

menu()
a = 1
b = 1
while a == b:
    choice = int(input())
    if choice == 1:
        #startGame()
        #intro()
        #hello()
        game()
        menu()

    if choice == 2:
        startGame()
        game()
        menu()
    if choice == 3:
        parameters(rand_begin_number,rand_end_number,Take)
        menu()
    if choice == 4:
        b = b + 1
        quit()
```

Comment: choice == int(input()) - это что вообще?

Comment: это только что исправил, сам увидел

Comment: Думаю, Вам в многопоточку.

Comment: это что значит ?

Comment: Объясните пожалуйста что имеете в виду ?

Answer (score 0):

тут какие то косяки с логикой игры, но так:

```py
from random import randint
from time import sleep


def intro():
    print('Приветствую в игре "Угадай число')
    sleep(1)
    print('Я загадаю случайное число в определенном диапазоне, ты должен его угадать за определенное количество попыток.')
    sleep(3)

def parameters(rand_begin_number,rand_end_number,Take):  # настройки
    print('1. Изменить диапазон цифр [от] [до]')
    print('2. Изменить количество попыток.')
    parameters_choice = input()
    parameters_choice = int(parameters_choice)

    if parameters_choice == 1:
        print('Введите желаемый диапазон:')
        rand_begin_number = int(input())
        rand_end_number = int(input())
        print('Диапазон установлен: [',rand_begin_number,']', '[',rand_end_number, ']')
    return rand_begin_number,rand_end_number

    if parameters_choice == 2:
        print('Установите количество попыток:')
        Take = int(input())
    return Take


def hello():
    print('Представься, как тебя зовут ?')
    name = input()
    print('Начнём игру,',name,'.')
    return name

def game():
    global choice # <--------------#####################---------------------
    while choice == 1: 
        primary_rand_begin_number = 1 
        primary_rand_end_number = 20
        primary_Take = 5
        real_number = randint(primary_rand_begin_number,primary_rand_end_number)
        take = primary_Take
    else:
        alt_rand_begin_number = rand_begin_number 
        alt_rand_end_number = rand_end_number
        alt_Take = Take
        real_number = randint(alt_rand_begin_number,alt_rand_end_number)
        take = alt_Take
        fake_take = 1
        print('Введи число:')
        print('ЧИСЛО', real_number)

    for fake_take in range(take):
        user_number = input()
        user_number = int(user_number)
        take -=1
        if user_number != real_number:
            print('Попробуй ещё.')
            print('У тебя осталось', take, 'попыток.')

        if user_number == real_number:
            print('Ты угадал загаданное число [',real_number,'] за', fake_take + 1, 'попыток')
            break

    if user_number != real_number:
        print('Попытки исчерпаны\n')
        print('Загаданное число было:', real_number,'\n')


def startGame():
    print('Начать игру --- нажмите Enter')
    input()

def menu():
    print('1. Начать игру.')
    print('2. Начать заного.(без интро)')
    print('3. Изменить настройки игры.')
    print('4. Выйти из игры.')
    choice = int(input())
    return choice

def quit():
    print('Пока !')
    sleep(1)

menu()
a = 1
b = 1
while a == b:
    choice = int(input())
    if choice == 1:
        #startGame()
        #intro()
        #hello()
        game()
        menu()

    if choice == 2:
        startGame()
        game()
        menu()
    if choice == 3:
        parameters(rand_begin_number,rand_end_number,Take)
        menu()
    if choice == 4:
        b = b + 1
        quit()
```

все вроде работает

Comment: Не могли бы Вы пояснить внесённые изменения?

Comment: а что тут пояснять, автор сам сказал что разные пространства имен, локальные и глобальные, вот я и закинул в локальный namespace game() глобальную choice методом global, очевидно же

Comment: Спасибо. Лично мне это было неочевидно. Всё-таки в коде 100+ строк и играть в игру "найди 10 отличий" совсем не хочется.

Comment: ну я там пометил длинной стрелочкой изменения, я думал вы просили пояснить смысл метода)

Comment: Я конечно не специалист, но у меня этот код ну вообще не работает, тут и невооруженным взглядом видны проблемы в логике. Интересно как он заработал у вас?

Comment: @whizz169 ну, я вроде где то что то подредактировал, опробовал свое изменение, вопросы пошли ну я и забил)